# SQL sub Query to return a value for each row in query

Tags: sql, subquery, row

This question is a little hard to word, so I'll show you what I need

```
CASE

WHEN t1.RANGE_START = t1.RANGE_END
    Then (select RANGE_START 
    from .dbo.t1

    )

END as Value
```

what I'm trying to do is make it so that if range start and range end are equal then just use the range start as the value for each row.

I understand that what the query is doing right now is trying to select *every* Range_start for *each* value where the range_start = range_end so how do I limit the sub query to only pull that value for the current row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of guessing without trying I am afraid but you can't be far away...something like this.

```
SELECT
  CASE 
     WHEN t1.RANGE_START = t1.RANGE_END 
        THEN t1.RANGE_START
       ELSE t1.RANGE_END
     END AS Value,
  column1,
  column2,
  column3
FROM dbo.t1
```

I usually find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) resource pretty useful